# How to solve BigCommerce Stencil CLI 404 error?

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

I need to work on an existing Big Commerce site.

I've downloaded and installed Stencil CLI with no issues.

I've logged into my BigCommerce site and set up a Stencil API Token, I've downloaded the theme, extracted it and run `npm install`. I then ran:

`stencil init --url https://yourstore.com/ --token 19d3ae6-dc15-4af9-bead-a2c703aa7b --port 3000`

with no issues. Then ran `stencil start`.

However, I get the error:

> not ok -- Error: The BigCommerce Store you are pointing to either does
> not exist or is not available at this time. Error details: Request
> failed with status code 404

I've tried both my store's URL and `https://store-12345.mybigcommerce.com/` and ensured there was a `/` at the end of the url.

The site loads fine - I can access the front end without issue.

I've running version 3.2.1 of Stencil and version 12.18.3 of node.

Would anyone know what I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, [this may help](https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues/665) -- it suggests disabling ssl checks and since the cli is only used for dev purposes this isn't a dangerous decision. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I get the same error

Comment: You may need to re-generate a new token and try again, be sure to select "Stencil-CLI token" and "publish theme" as the permission level. The cli had an update to 3.3.0 which added support for the channels directly in stencil-cli. So any older tokens generated before this change may experience errors.

Comment: In addition to this, could you verify if the store you're working on is a stencil or blueprint theme? https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Which-Theme-Platform-do-I-have